# Program prints out declined for all variables entered, but I am trying to make it only print that out when a specific letter is entered e.g.'u'?

Tags: c, if-statement, scanf, logical-operators

I'm trying to create a program that will print Accepted when a letter of the alphabet it entered, excluding `u`. When `u` is entered it prints declined.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char val;

    printf("Enter your letter : \n");
    val = scanf("%c", &val);
    
    if (val == 'u' || (val >= '0' || val <= '9'))
        printf("DECLINED\n");
    else
        print("ACCEPTED\n");

    return (0);
}
```

Comment: maybe it'll be a good idea not to test the non existent variable c, but to test the variable val instead

Comment: Mistake on the question my code is val, my bad. Still prints out all as declined

Comment: the other mistake is that you assign the return value of `scanf()` to `val`. This will overwrite the read character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to accept letters i think you should convert char to int (ASCII values) and check like this

```
      #include <stdio.h>

      int main () {
      char val;
      int c;
      printf("Enter your letter :\n");

      scanf("%c", &val);
      c = (int) (val);

      if ( ( val != 'u')   &&  (c >= 97 && c <= 122) ||  (c >= 65 && c <= 90)){
             printf("ACCEPTED\n");
      } else {
             printf("DECLINED\n");
      }


      return (0);
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the condition:

```
if (val == 'u' || (val >= '0' && val <= '9'))
```

Rather than:

```
if (val == 'u' || (val >= '0' || val <= '9'))
```

**And this is an error:**

```
val = scanf("%c, &val);
```

Do this simply:

```
scanf("%c", &val);
```